# htaccess 301 redirects to wrong url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I did a 301 redirect with htaccess but dont understand why the final link is wrong?

This is what I end up with http://example.com/about?/about-us/

Rather than a clean intended http://example.com/about

This is my htaccess code

```
Redirect 301 /about-us/ /about
```

To me this looks fine... What have I done wrong?

I need to redirect from http://www.example.com/about-us/

I've also tried

```
Redirect 301 /about-us/ http://example.com/about
```

Comment: Ok so I got it to work by adding ? at the end. Such as Redirect 301 /about-us/ http://example.com/about? but now I have ? at the end of url... :/

Comment: I think this might have something to do with removing index.php from Expressionengine htaccess rule not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using apache `mod_rewrite` instead of using `Redirect`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ /about [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks a lot!